# Group By with Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, group-by, entity-framework-core, sum, linq-to-entities

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXbji.png)I have a code. And there you need to make a grouping by name.

```
 //<date,<partid,amount>>
            Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, double>> emSpending = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, double>>();
            foreach (Orders order in db.Orders.ToList())
            {
                foreach (OrderItems orderitem in order.OrderItems.ToList())
                {
                    if (!emSpending.ContainsKey(order.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM"))) emSpending.Add(order.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM"), new Dictionary<int, double>());
                    if (!emSpending[order.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM")].ContainsKey(Convert.ToInt32(orderitem.PartID))) emSpending[order.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM")].Add(Convert.ToInt32(orderitem.PartID), 0);
                    emSpending[order.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM")][Convert.ToInt32(orderitem.PartID)] += Convert.ToDouble(orderitem.Amount);
                }
            }

            DataGridViewColumn col1 = new DataGridViewColumn();
            col1.CellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
            col1.Name = "Department";
            col1.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
            col1.HeaderText = "Department";
            dgvEMSpending.Columns.Add(col1);
            foreach (string date in emSpending.Keys)
            {
                DataGridViewColumn col = new DataGridViewColumn();
                col.Name = date;
                col.HeaderText = date;
                col.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
                col.CellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();

                dgvEMSpending.Columns.Add(col);
            }
            List<string> allKey = emSpending.Keys.ToList();
            foreach (string date in allKey)
                if (date == "Department") continue;
                else
                {
                    dgvEMSpending.Rows.Add();
                    foreach (int partid in emSpending[date].Keys)
                    {
                        dgvEMSpending.Rows[dgvEMSpending.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[0].Value = db.Parts.Where(x => x.ID == partid).SingleOrDefault().Name.GroupBy(Name);
                        for (int i = 1; i < dgvEMSpending.Columns.Count; i++)
                        {
                            if (!emSpending.ContainsKey(dgvEMSpending.Columns[i].Name)) emSpending.Add(dgvEMSpending.Columns[i].Name, new Dictionary<int, double>());
                            if (!emSpending[dgvEMSpending.Columns[i].Name].ContainsKey(partid)) emSpending[dgvEMSpending.Columns[i].Name].Add(partid, 0);
                            double val = emSpending[dgvEMSpending.Columns[i].Name][partid];
                            dgvEMSpending.Rows[dgvEMSpending.RowCount - 1].Cells[i].Value = val;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

I tried to use group by myself, but something doesn't work. It just outputs the same names, and I want to group them so that there is a grouping. Pls helped to me.

Comment: would be good to extract only the important part of the code and show your results

Comment: here is a screen that outputs me and it is clear that there are identical departments, but I want to group and that the amount would be calculated

Answer (score 0):

Ok, a few issues to help you out first. This code:

```
        foreach (Orders order in db.Orders.ToList())
        {
            foreach (OrderItems orderitem in order.OrderItems.ToList())
            {
                if (!emSpending.ContainsKey(order.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM"))) emSpending.Add(order.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM"), new Dictionary<int, double>());
                if (!emSpending[order.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM")].ContainsKey(Convert.ToInt32(orderitem.PartID))) emSpending[order.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM")].Add(Convert.ToInt32(orderitem.PartID), 0);
                emSpending[order.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM")][Convert.ToInt32(orderitem.PartID)] += Convert.ToDouble(orderitem.Amount);
            }
        }
```

Right off the bat this is going to trip lazy loading on OrderItems. If you have 10 orders 1-10 you're going to be running 11 queries against the database:

```
SELECT * FROM Orders;
SELECT * FROM OrderItems WHERE OrderId = 1;
SELECT * FROM OrderItems WHERE OrderId = 2;
// ...
SELECT * FROM OrderItems WHERE OrderId = 10;
```

Now if you have 100 orders or 1000 orders, you should see the problem. At a minimum ensure that if you are touching a collection or reference on entities you are loading, eager load it with `Include`:

```
foreach (Orders order in db.Orders.Include(x => x.OrderItems).ToList())
```

This will run a single query that fetches the Orders and their OrderItems. However, if you have a LOT of rows this is going to take a while and consume a LOT of memory.

The next tip is "only load what you need". You need 1 field from Order and 2 fields from OrderItem. So why load *everything* from both tables??

```
var orderItemDetails = db.Orders
    .SelectMany(o => o.OrderItems.Select(oi => new { o.Date, oi.PartId, oi.Amount })
    .ToList();
```

This would give us just the Order date, and each Part ID and Amount.  Now that this data is in memory we can group it to populate your desired dictionary structure without having to iterate over it row by row.

```
var emSpending = orderItemDetails.GroupBy(x => x.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM"))
     .ToDictionary(g => g.Key,
          g => g.GroupBy(y => y.PartId)
              .ToDictionary(g2 => g2.Key, g2 => g2.Sum(z => z.Amount)));
```

Depending on the Types in your entities you may need to insert casts. This first groups the outer dictionary of the yyyy-MM of the order dates, then it groups the remaining data for each date by part ID, and sums the Amount.

Now relating to your question, from your code example I'm guessing the problem area you are facing is this line:

```
dgvEMSpending.Rows[dgvEMSpending.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[0].Value = db.Parts
    .Where(x => x.ID == partid)
    .SingleOrDefault().Name.GroupBy(Name);
```

Now the question would be to explain what exactly you are expecting from this? You are fetching a single Part by ID. How would you expect this to be "grouped"?

If you want to display the Part name instead of the PartId then I believe you would just want to `Select` the Part Name:

```
dgvEMSpending.Rows[dgvEMSpending.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[0].Value = db.Parts
    .Where(x => x.ID == partid)
    .Select(x => x.Name)
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

We can go one better to fetch the Part names for each used product in one hit using our loaded order details:

```
var partIds = orderItemDetails
    .Select(x=> x.PartId)
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();

var partDetails = db.Parts
    .Where(x => partIds.Contains(x.ID))
    .ToDictionary(x => x.ID, x => x.Name);
```

This fetches us a dictionary set indexed by ID for the part names, it would be done outside of the loop after we had loaded the orderItemDetails. Now we don't have to go to the DB with every row:

```
dgvEMSpending.Rows[dgvEMSpending.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[0].Value = partDetails[partId];
```

Comment: It's just that I have the same details but under different IDs and they all sort of come out, and I want the records to be grouped by name.